# Find the total area between the curve and the $x$-axis.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $$y= \frac{2}{x^2},\;\quad 1 \le x \le 2$$

I'm asked to find the area between the curve and the $x$-axis.

I think we have to use integrals to solve this? I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you remember the definition of the area between a curve and the axis ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use an integral:

$$\begin{align} \int_1^2 \dfrac 2{x^2} \,dx & = \int_1^2 2x^{-2}\,dx \\ \\ & = \dfrac {2x^{-1}}{-1}\Big|_1^2 \\ \\ & = -\dfrac{2}{x}\Big|_1^2 \\ \\ & = \left(\dfrac {-2}2\right) - \left(\dfrac {-2}1\right) \\ \\ &= - 1 - (-2) =  1\end{align}$$

Graphing a function is usually helpful for better understanding the region of integration:

[image]

Here, we want to integrate the area $1 \leq x \leq 2$, the "upper curve" $y = \dfrac 2{x^2}$ and the "lower curve" $y = 0$ (the x-axis). So our bounds of integration are from $x = 1$ to $x = 2$. And the integrand is equal to $$\underbrace{\dfrac{2}{x^2}}_{\text{upper curve}} - \underbrace{0}_{\text{lower curve}} = \dfrac{2}{x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble remembering what $-2/2$ was. :)

Comment: I like the answer illustrated by a figure $\ddot\smile$+1

Comment: Love graphics! And u know that. +)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.  Since $1\le x\le 2$, you want the integral of $\frac2{x^2}$ from $1$ to $2$:  $$\int_1^2\frac2{x^2}\text dx=-\left.\frac2x\right|_1^2=-1-(-2)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ Area \; = \int\limits_1^2 \frac{2}{x^2} = -\frac{2}{2} - (- \frac{2}{1}) = -1 + 2 = 1$$